# Why I'm getting syntax error on 1st line?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I installed pylint on my PC. But while I'm writing some code, for instance:

```
def my_logger(original_func):
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename = f'{original_func.__name__}.log', level = logging.INFO)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.info(f'Ran with {*args} and {**kwargs}.')

        return original_func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Pylint raises syntax-error and underlines keyword 'def':

`invalid syntax(<fstring>, line 1) pylint syntax-error [1,1]`

Answer (score 1):

`*args` and `**kwargs` are not expressions; they are syntax restricted to certain contexts (such as function calls, function declarations, array literals, multiple assignments etc). The f-string `{...}` interpolator expects an expression.

This works:

```
logging.info(f'Ran with {args} and {kwargs}.')
```